# Shell scripting comparison for special charecter

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Need help in comparing the value of special character ie., - inside shell script.

Trying to extract initial 4 columns

```
command1 |  awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}' | while read pid 
do 
echo $pid 
done
```

getting below output

```
TOPIC PARTITION CURRENT-OFFSET  LAG 
Topic1 0 - 810
```

I wanted to include the condition to compare the value of CURRENT-OFFSET if its is equal to - and greater than 500, i need to print message A else message B

I tried

```
command |  awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}' | while read pid; do
if [[ $pid -eq "-" ]] && [[ $pid -gt 500 ]]; then
echo "message A"
else
echo "message B"
fi
done
```

Not sure how to check the value of - and compare. Need help

Comment: what field exactly you want to compare against 500? since `CURRENT-OFFSET` can't be equal to `-` and greater than 500 at the same time...

Comment: I am trying to compare the value of CURRENT-OFFSET, which can be either - or any positive number based on command output

Comment: The way it's written now, `pid` contains the entire line. I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want, but it might help to use something like `read field1 field2 field3 field4` (or more appropriate names), and then test something like `if [[ $field3 = "-" ]] && [[ $field4 -gt 500 ]]`. Also: use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net).